# How do I find the FamilyGUID of an exsting database

Tags: sql-server, restore

When executing a `RESTORE` command, I understand that SQL Server ensures that an existing database is not being overwritten by a different database.  This check can be bypassed using `REPLACE`.

I understand that SQL Server uses the backup file's `FamilyGUID` to determine whether the database being restored is the same as the database being overwritten.  Is this correct?

I understand that the `FamilyGUID` of the backup file can be determined using

```
RESTORE headeronly FROM DISK = N'Q:\MyBackup.bak'
```

But how can I find the FamilyGUID of the database that is being overwritten?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the catalog view - [sys.database_recovery_status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-recovery-status-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) as DatabaseName, database_guid, family_guid
FROM master.sys.database_recovery_status
```

You can make your restore process more sophisticated by comparing the  `family_guid` of the backup file and the database to be restored.

Just dump the info of `RESTORE headeronly` into a temp table and use above query to compare. If they are different then there is a problem.